# Display Order column in SharePoint list that auto updates all items when one changed

Tags: sharepoint, list, moss, sql-order-by

I have a document library that has a set of douments in it and I'd like them to be ordered in the library/view in a user definable way. So ideally I'd like to add a DisplayOrder or Priority column and have this set by the users. Each number in this column MUST be unique and should update other items in the list when a user "inserts" a document in the middle of the order or changes the order in anyway.

The  only way I can figure doing this is to run a workflow that does the grunt work, but was hopeing that there might be an easier way.

This is all on MOSS 2007.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Other than workflow, you can have a event handler too. I don't think there is no way to force uniqueness in MOSS 2007 other than custom code.

Comment: OK, so I finally got round to "solving" this using jQuery sortable on a custom page which updates all records to the index() after sorting. This is OK for me because I know there wont be many items in the list and its really user friendly